# ROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'writeValue')

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

I am getting the error when I go to update/edit users. The other users were having MgModel issues, and I checked, I don't have that. One clue taht might help us figure this out is that the styling of the page is also off.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
in.ts:12 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'writeValue')
    at setUpControl (forms.mjs:2939:23)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.mjs:4771:9)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.mjs:5321:43)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:5266:18)
    at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1573:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2497:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2456:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2407:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9100:17)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.mjs:9083:5)
```

Here is my TS file:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { User, UsersService  } from '@eshop-repository/users';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-users-form',
  templateUrl: './users-form.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class UsersFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;
  editmode = false;
  currentUserId!: string;
  countries = [];

  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private location: Location,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._initUserForm();
    //this._getCountries();
    this._checkEditMode();
  }

  private _initUserForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      phone: ['', Validators.required],
      isAdmin: [false],
      street: [''],
      apartment: [''],
      zip: [''],
      city: [''],
      country: ['']
    });
  }

  // private _getCountries() {
  //   this.countries = this.usersService.getCountries();
  // }

  private _addUser(user: User) {
    this.usersService.createUser(user).subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Success',
          detail: `User ${user.name} is created!`
        });
        timer(2000)
          .toPromise()
          .then(() => {
            this.location.back();
          });
      },
      () => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'error',
          summary: 'Error',
          detail: 'User is not created!'
        });
      }
    );
  }

  private _updateUser(user: User) {
    this.usersService.updateUser(user).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Success',
          detail: 'User is updated!'
        });
        timer(2000)
          .toPromise()
          .then(() => {
            this.location.back();
          });
      },
      () => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'error',
          summary: 'Error',
          detail: 'User is not updated!'
        });
      }
    );
  }

  private _checkEditMode() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.editmode = true;
        this.currentUserId = params['id'];
        this.usersService.getUser(params['id']).subscribe((user) => {
          this.userForm['name'].setValue(user.name);
          this.userForm['email'].setValue(user.email);
          this.userForm['phone'].setValue(user.phone);
          this.userForm['isAdmin'].setValue(user.isAdmin);
          this.userForm['street'].setValue(user.street);
          this.userForm['apartment'].setValue(user.apartment);
          this.userForm['zip'].setValue(user.zip);
          this.userForm['city'].setValue(user.city);
          this.userForm['country'].setValue(user.country);

          this.userForm['password'].setValidators([]);
          this.userForm['password'].updateValueAndValidity();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const user: User = {
      id: this.currentUserId,
      name: this.userForm['name'].value,
      email: this.userForm['email'].value,
      password: this.userForm['password'].value,
      phone: this.userForm['phone'].value,
      isAdmin: this.userForm['isAdmin'].value,
      street: this.userForm['street'].value,
      apartment: this.userForm['apartment'].value,
      zip: this.userForm['zip'].value,
      city: this.userForm['city'].value,
      country: this.userForm['country'].value
    };
    if (this.editmode) {
      this._updateUser(user);
    } else {
      this._addUser(user);
    }
  }

  onCancle() {
    this.location.back();
  }

  get userForm() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<p-toast></p-toast>
<div class="admin-page">
  <p-card [header]="editmode ? 'Edit User' : 'Add User'" subheader="You can add or edit users here">
    <div class="p-grid p-mb-5">
      <div class="p-col-12">
        <p-toolbar>
          <div class="p-toolbar-group-left"></div>
          <div class="p-toolbar-group-right">
            <p-button
              styleClass="p-button-primary p-mr-2"
              [label]="editmode ? 'Update' : 'Create'"
              icon="pi pi-plus"
              (click)="onSubmit()"
            ></p-button>
            <p-button
              styleClass="p-button-secondary"
              label="Cancle"
              icon="pi pi-arrow-circle-left"
              (click)="onCancle()"
            ></p-button>
          </div>
        </p-toolbar>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-grid">
      <div class="p-col-12">
        <form [formGroup]="form">
          <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid p-grid">
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input formControlName="name" id="name" type="text" pInputText />
              <small *ngIf="userForm['name'].invalid && isSubmitted" class="p-error"
                >Name is required</small
              >
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input formControlName="email" id="email" type="text" pInputText />
              <small *ngIf="userForm['email'].invalid && isSubmitted" class="p-error"
                >
                <span>*ngIf="userForm['email'].invalid && isSubmitted">email is required</span>
                <span *ngIf="userForm['email'].invalid && isSubmitted">email is invalid</span>
                >
                </small>
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input formControlName="password" id="password" type="password" pInputText />
              <small *ngIf="userForm['password'].invalid && isSubmitted" class="p-error"
                >Password is required</small
              >
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="color">Phone</label><br />
              <p-inputMask
                mask="(999) 999-9999"
                formControlName="phone"
                placeholder="(999) 999-9999"
              ></p-inputMask>
              <small *ngIf="userForm['phone'].invalid && isSubmitted" class="p-error"
                >phone is required</small
              >
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="isAdmin">Is Admin</label><br />
              <p-inputSwitch formControlName="isAdmin"></p-inputSwitch>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid p-grid">
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="street">Street</label>
              <input formControlName="street" id="street" type="text" pInputText />
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="street">Apartment</label>
              <input formControlName="apartment" id="apartment" type="text" pInputText />
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="street">Zip Code</label>
              <input formControlName="zip" id="zip" type="text" pInputText />
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="city">City</label>
              <input formControlName="city" id="city" type="text" pInputText />
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-4">
              <label for="country">Country</label><br />
              <p-dropdown
                [options]="countries"
                formControlName="country"
                optionLabel="name"
                optionValue="id"
                [filter]="true"
                filterBy="name"
                [showClear]="true"
                placeholder="Select a Country"
              ></p-dropdown>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </p-card>
</div>
```

And I forgot to add the my service TS file (in case it is needed):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
  apiURLUsers = environment.apiUrl + 'users';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   // countriesLib.registerLocale(require('i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json'));
  }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.apiURLUsers);
  }

  getUser(userId: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.apiURLUsers}/${userId}`);
  }

  createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.apiURLUsers, user);
  }

  updateUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.put<User>(`${this.apiURLUsers}/${user.id}`, user);
  }

  deleteUser(userId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete<any>(`${this.apiURLUsers}/${userId}`);
  }

  getUsersCount(): Observable<number> {
    return this.http
      .get<number>(`${this.apiURLUsers}/get/count`)
      .pipe(map((objectValue: any) => objectValue.userCount));
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I forgot to add this to my app module ts

```
import { InputMaskModule } from 'primeng/inputmask';
```

I was using input mask for phone number, the issue seems to be gone now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to insert an *ngIf in your form tag like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
```

Angular tries to check the form but in ngOnInit (where you called the creation of your form) hook the view part is already been created so the check will fail resulting with an error like the one you mentioned

Comment: Thank you Alessandro. But in this case, the issue was I had not imported Inputmask for the phone number: such as import { InputMaskModule } from 'primeng/inputmask';
I still think your answe is also acceptable.

Comment: You're welcome, the most important thing is that you solved your problem. However consider adding the *ngIf that could avoid other errors :)